# Position: fixed not working as intended for modal window in React (Next.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a modal window in React, but for some reason, using `position: fixed` sets the position of the modal window relative to the page as opposed to the browser window. This is what it looks like (note: the black boxes were edited in for privacy).
[image]

Here's the code for this page particularly, including the modal window component, which is at the top.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import utilStyles from '../styles/util.module.css';
import styles from '../styles/education.module.css';
import courseData from '../public/courses.json' assert {type: 'json'};
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCalendar } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { faXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

function Modal({ isShow, handleClick, longDescription, children }) {
    return (isShow ? 
        <div className="modal-outer" onClick={handleClick}>
            <div className="modal-inner">
                {children}
                <button className="exit"><FontAwesomeIcon className="exit-icon" icon={faXmark}/></button>
                <p className="course-description-long">{longDescription}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     : "");
}

function CourseContent({ courseName, shortDescription }) {
    return (
        <>
            <h3 className="course-name">{courseName}</h3>
            <p className="course-description-short">{shortDescription}</p>
        </>
    )
}

function CourseCard({ courseName, shortDescription, longDescription}){
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);

    function handleClick () {
        setIsShow(!isShow);
    }

  return (
    <>
        <li key={courseName} className="course-card" onClick={handleClick}>
            <CourseContent courseName={courseName} shortDescription={shortDescription}/>
        </li>
        <Modal isShow={isShow} 
        longDescription="this is the long description"
        handleClick={handleClick}>
            <CourseContent courseName={courseName} shortDescription={shortDescription}/>
        </Modal>
        
     </>
  )
}

function DegreeInfo(props) {
  const { universityName, degreeType, degreeName, startYear, endYear, courses } = props;
  return (
    <li>
      <p>{universityName}</p>
      <p>{degreeType}.&nbsp;{degreeName}</p>
      <div className="date-container">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendar}/>
        <time dateTime={`${startYear}/${endYear}`}>{startYear}&ndash;{endYear}</time>
      </div>
      <ul className="course-cards-list">
        {courses.map(course => 
          <CourseCard key={course.courseName} courseName={course.courseName} shortDescription={course.shortDescription} />
        )}
      </ul>
    </li>
  )
}

export default function EducationPage() {
  const yearDecoder = {1: "First-year", 2: "Second-year", 3: "Third-year"};
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Education | Alé Pouroullis</title>
      </Head>
      <div  className={`${utilStyles.container} ${utilStyles['float-in']}`}>
        
        <h1>Education</h1>
        <section className="university">
            <h2>Tertiary</h2>
            <ul className={`${styles['main-list']}`}>
                    {courseData.degrees.map(degree => {
                    const courses = degree.courses;
                    courses.sort(sortByYear);
                    return (<DegreeInfo key={degree.name} universityName={degree.universityName}
                                degreeType={degree.type} degreeName={degree.degreeName}
                                startYear={degree.startYear} endYear={degree.endYear}
                                courses={courses}/>)
                    })}
                </ul>
        </section>
        <section className="courses">
          <h2>Courses</h2>
          <ul className="main-list">
            <li className="main-list-item">
              <span className="main-list-text">Mathematics for Machine Learning Specialization</span>
              <ul className="sub-list">
                <li className="sub-list-item"><span className="sub-list-text">Linear Algebra</span></li>
                <li className="sub-list-item"><span className="sub-list-text">Multivariable Calculus</span></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function sortByYear(a, b) {
  if (a.year < b.year) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.year > b.year) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And here's the styling for the modal window:

```
.modal-outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

I'm rather new to React, so excuse this if it's a complete rookie mistake.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this css for your modal component: `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translatex(-50%);`
this should center your modal in center of screen.

If you wish to try a cool nice way, you can try `React.createPortal` function, read about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the first part (the CSS) didn't quite work for me. But the React portal did! It's exactly what I thinking of using to solve the problem, but it seemed intractable without a feature like portals.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this css for .modal-outer.

```
.modal-outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
```